# I want to store the user data on a notepad to find the mutual friend details and some more things but I'm struggling to store as a txt file

Tags: java, file

Main.java:

```
package face;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception
    {
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
            SignUp m = new SignUp();
         while (true) {
                System.out.
                        println("1)Customer Sign-up\n2)Customer signin\n3)Stop Program");
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        m.customerSignUp();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        m.customerSignin();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.exit(0);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

signup.java:

```
package face;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SignUp implements Serializable {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<User> customer = new ArrayList<User>();
    Home home = new Home();
   void customerSignUp() {
        System.out.println("Enter the details to sign-up");
        System.out.println("Enter the id");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the name");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("enter the pass");
        String pass = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the age");
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the gender");
        String gender = sc.next();
       
        int d = 0;
        if (customer.size() > 1) {
            for (User c : customer) {
                if (c.id == (id)) {
                    d++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (d== 0) {
            customer.add(new User(id, name, pass, age, gender));
            System.out.println("Back to home page");
        } else {
            System.out.println("User id already exist");
        }

        }
    void customerSignin() {
        System.out.println("Enter id: ");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("password to Login:");
        String pass = sc.next();
        int f = 0;
       User currcustomer = null;
        for (User c : customer) {
            if (c.id == (id) && c.password.equals(pass)) {
                currcustomer = c;
                f++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (f == 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Login or Password");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Logined Successfully...\nWelcome " + currcustomer.name + "\nage " + currcustomer.age
                    + "\ngender " + currcustomer.gender);
            home.enterHome(currcustomer);
        }
        }
    public void view() {
        System.out.println("Enter the user name");
        String name = sc.next();
        for (User c : customer) {
            if (name.equals(c.name)) {
                System.out.println("you found the user" + c.name + "\nage " + c.age + "\ngender " + c.gender);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("user name not found");
            }
        }
        
    }
    public void viewAll(User user) {
        if (customer.size() > 1) {
            for (User c : customer) {
                if (c.id != user.id)
                    System.out.println("User: " + c.name + "\nId: " + c.id + "\nage " + c.age + "\ngender " + c.gender);
            }
            System.out.println("Do you like to raise a friend request to an account? \n1.Yes  2.No");
            int yes = sc.nextInt();
            if (yes == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter the account Id to whom you want to raise request:");
                int requesterId = sc.nextInt();
                raiseRequest(requesterId, user);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no users yet other than u");
        }
    }
    public void viewParticularAccount(User user, int targetId) {
        User targetUser = null;
        for (User c : customer) {
            if (c.id != user.id && c.id == targetId) {
                System.out.println("You are visiting: " + c.name + "\nage " + c.age + "\ngender " + c.gender);
                targetUser = c;
            }
        }
        if (targetUser != null) {
            System.out.println("Do you like to raise a friend request to an account? \n1.Yes  2.No");
            int yes = sc.nextInt();
            if (yes == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter the account Id to whom you want to raise request:");
                int requesterId = sc.nextInt();
                raiseRequest(requesterId, user);
            }
            if (yes == 2) {
                System.out.println("Do you like to check the mutual friends list of this account? \n1.Yes 2.No");
                int showMutualview = sc.nextInt();
                if (showMutualview == 1) {
                    showMutualFriends(user, targetUser);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no users with the given Id :-) ");
        }
    }
    public void raiseRequest(int requesterId, User user) {
        for (User c : customer) {
            if (c.id == requesterId) {
                c.requesters.add(user);
            }
        }
    }
    public void showMutualFriends(User user, User targetUser) {
        for (User u : customer) {
            if (user.friends.contains(u) && targetUser.friends.contains(u)) {
                System.out.println("User : " + u.name + "\nage " + u.age + "\ngender " + u.gender);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created a signup program to get the user details and I stored temporarily, but I need to store it under text file in a notepad for the further programming purpose. But I don't know how to store the user details in a notepad as a txt file. I want to store the received user details in a notepad.

Answer (score 0):

```java
   try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write(text);
        writer.close;
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this should write text to a file, given that the file inputted is a txt file

Comment: where to write this code in on code and where to set my file path

Comment: `File file = new File("filename.txt);`
thats good enough for a file path and you should put the code in my answer wherever you want to store the user details in this file